# Byte string literal with non-ascii characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, internationalization

Apparently, I can do that in Python 2.7:

```
value = '國華'
```

It seems Python is using an encoding to encode the characters in the string literal to a byte string. What is that encoding? Is that the encoding defined in `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, the encoding of the source file, or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Is that line in the source file, or on the command line? Also, do you actually want to learn the intricacies of encoding in Python 2.7 (which is slightly different from both 2.6 and 3.x), or are you just trying to work around a problem that could be solved by sticking a `u` before the quotes?

Comment: I am actually trying to learn the intricacies of encoding in Python 2.7. And this is in a source file, but I'm also interested to know if that's different in a command prompt.

Comment: Python 2.7 says not to do this, but if you're interested in what CPython 2.7 does if you do it anyway… the literal bytes inside the quotes in the source file (e.g., '\xe5\x9c\x8b\xe8\x8f\xaf') are stored as a byte string. Since the source file's coding declaration may not be the same as `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, there may be no way for you to safely interpret it, but the bytes are there. And if the two encodings are the same, and so is the terminal's, and that encoding can handle those characters, you can even "print value" and see what you expect. Is that what you want, or is there more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getdefaultencoding` has no relation to the encoding of the source file or the terminal.  It is the encoding used to convert byte strings implicitly to Unicode strings and should always be 'ascii' on Python 2.X ('utf8' on Python 3.X).

On Python 2.X, your line of code in a script with no encoding declared produces an error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x87' in file ...
```

The actual non-ASCII character may vary, but it won't work without an encoding declaration.  An encoding declaration is *required* to use non-ASCII characters on Python 2.X.  The encoding declaration *must match* the source file encoding.  For example:

```
# coding: utf8
value = '國華'
```

when saved as cp936 produces:

```
SyntaxError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 9: invalid start byte
```

When the encoding is correct, the bytes in the byte string are literally what is in the source file, so it will contain the encoded bytes of the characters.  When Python parses a Unicode string the bytes are decoded using the declared source encoding to Unicode.  Note the difference when printing a UTF-8 byte string and a Unicode string on a cp936 console:

```
# coding: utf8
value = '國華'
print value,repr(value)
value = u'國華'
print value,repr(value)
```

Output:

```
鍦嬭彲 '\xe5\x9c\x8b\xe8\x8f\xaf'
國華 u'\u570b\u83ef'
```

The byte string contains the 3-byte UTF-8 encodings of the two characters, but displayed incorrectly since the byte sequence isn't understood by a cp936 terminal.  Unicode is printed correctly, and the string contains the Unicode code points decoded from the UTF-8 bytes of the source file.

Note the difference when declaring and using the encoding that matches the terminal:

```
# coding: cp936
value = '國華'
print value,repr(value)
value = u'國華'
print value,repr(value)
```

Output:

```
國華 '\x87\xf8\xc8A'
國華 u'\u570b\u83ef'
```

The content of the byte string is now the 2-byte cp936 encodings of the two characters ('A' equivalent to '\x41') and is displayed correctly since the terminal understands the cp936 byte sequence.  The Unicode string contains the same Unicode code points for the two characters as the previous example because the source byte sequence was decoded using the declared source encoding to Unicode.

If a script has a correct source encoding declaration and uses Unicode strings for text, it  will display the correct characters<sup>1</sup> regardless of terminal encoding<sup>2</sup>.  It will throw a `UnicodeEncodeError` if the terminal doesn't support the character rather than display the wrong character.

A final note: Python 2.X defaults to 'ascii' encoding unless declared otherwise and allows non-ASCII characters in byte strings if the encoding supports them.  Python 3.X defaults to 'utf8' encoding (so make sure to save in that encoding or declare otherwise), and does **not** allow non-ASCII characters in byte strings.

<sup>1</sup>If the terminal font supports the character.
<sup>2</sup>If the terminal encoding supports the character.

Answer (score -1):

```
value = b'國華'
```

is meaningless (the `b` is implied in Python 2.x) - why do you want a *byte*string that contains *characters*? Python simply reproduces the bytes in whatever encoding your terminal/editor use. What you want is a *character* string:

```
value = u'國華'
```

In a source code file (as opposed to an interactive shell), don't forget to [declare the encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) by adding the following line to the beginning of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Well apparently the Python designers didn't think that was meaningless since they made it valid. You didn't really answer my question, which encoding does Python use when I run that line, how can I find out from code?

Comment: When you run that line in the interactive shell, or in a source file with an encoding declaration, or… what?

Comment: @Flavien non-ASCII characters in byte literals are an historical artifact. There is no code that makes them valid, they are just accidentally accepted, and that dates back to the time when Python didn't have clear byte vs character string semantics. Non-ASCII characters in byte literals are not valid anymore; they have been [removed from Python 3](http://ideone.com/f1iLN). Python doesn't use any encoding when you run that line. The file is a string of bytes, and so is the value of the bytes object the literal produces.

Comment: Ok, so it's using the encoding of the file. That's pretty bad design. To bad no one is using Python 3.

Comment: @Flavien: You don't have to use Python 3, you can just use Unicode literals and strings in Python 2.7 and get the same effect. The only problems 2.7 causes here are (a) letting you store a non-ASCII string in a byte string without specifying an encoding, and (b) interpreting non-ASCII input without a specified encoding. Python 3 makes both of those things illegal; 2.7 deprecates them and leaves the meaning undefined. If you just don't do those things, there's no problem.